# Adding background covers rounded corner [CSS/Twitter's Bootstrap]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using Twitter's [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) to give my site a consistent look, and I'm running into issues when I add a background to a table's `thead tr`. Here's CSS from Bootstrap:

```
.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: separate;
  *border-collapse: collapsed;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child th:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child td:first-child {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}
```

Here's my CSS:

```
tr.title
{
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#333333), to(#222222));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<thead>
<tr class="title">
<th colspan="5"><strong><a href="{$url}">{$name}</a></strong><br />{$description}</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

The problem is that the top left rounded corner gets removed with the `.title` background. When I remove the background code it comes back. How can I fix this?

Comment: What browser?  It seems IE9 has trouble clipping background gradients to border radius. Maybe check out the background-clip property?

Comment: After fiddling around with it, it looks like the `th` was causing the issue for some reason. Adding identical `border-radius` definitions fixed it. And just for the record, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Ah yes - that makes sense, kind of.  The TR doesn't clip it's contents, which is why the straight corners of the TH were popping out.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the background image you loose the rounded corners,
you have to redefine the border radius:

Example :

```
.modal-header {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url('myimg.jpg');
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 3.0 you need to put your table into the panel.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <table class="backgrounded table">
        <thead>
        ....
<thead></table></div>
```

CSS:

```
.backgrounded thead {
   background: #499bea;    
}
```